# Will Ubuntu Snappy Core work on the BeagleBone boards

Tags: ubuntu-core, support, beagleboard

I'm becoming increasingly interested in using Ubuntu Snappy Core, instead of Debian for the BeagleBone.

However, I can't seem to understand if this would work well on the BeagleBone development boards. I've looked online but can't find an answer. Is it supported for use with the BeagleBone boards? Thanks